# Meteor unable access Collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm going through my first Meteor build, and I got to a certain point and hit a wall. I'm not able to access my collections, at first I thought it was an issue with my query syntax, but I don't think it is.

I've tried: `db.collection.find()` and it works as expected in the Mongo shell, but in the client, `db.collection.find()` returns `LocalCollection.Cursor` which just gives me a list of the functions and prototypes associated with the current collection.

`db.collection.find().fetch()` just returns `{}`.

Further info: I have *admin-ui* installed, and I have a schema set up through that. Current user is Admin, with admin role assigned.

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm at my wits end trying to debug this.

Comment: Just asking, did you publish the collection and subscribe to it?

Comment: As I understand it that's something that's maybe done a little further on - by default meteor isn't set to need subscriptions, correct?

Either way, I followed the steps and made sure the collection is published and subscribed.

...still looks the same with db.find().fetch() and my queries are returning the same thing.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you defined the collection. Something like `collection = new Mongo.Collection("collection");`. The collection should be accessible by both client and server. And leave out `db.`, just write `collection.find().fetch();`. And it should return [], an empty array if no item were found, not {} which is an object without properties.

Comment: If you have the autopublish package installed, you should be able to see your collection from the client without publish/subscribe. You can check out file `.meteor/packages` to see whether autopublish is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A checklist for *I can't see my data in Meteor questions*:

1. `$ meteor add autopublish`
2. Do you see your data now?

type:

```
console.log('My subscription has '+myCollection.find().count()+' documents!");
```

in your browser console.

3. If yes, then you haven't published and subscribed to your collection correctly:

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('myPublication',function(){
  return myCollection.find(); // or whatever subset you want for this user
});
```

Client:

```
var handle = Meteor.subscribe('myPublication');
```

4. `$ meteor remove autopublish`
5. Do you see your data now?
6. Yes - problem solved
7. No, are you checking too soon? You might need to wait for your subscription to be *ready*. This is typically done in the router but can also be done by checking the `ready()` state of the subscription handle.

code:

```
if ( handle.ready() ) {
  console.log('My subscription has '+myCollection.find().count()+' documents!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Being published was definitely the issue. Weird thing is I know the data was there, then I went to find it via selecting by date and it stopped updating on the client, but I also decided to try some other things with the front end before I committed, so maybe adding/removing packages removed autopublish or something.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo has a dedicated API for mongodb operations and it is slightly different than mongodb's own API's.

In meteor world, you first "define a collection" (on both the server and the client in its most basic form)

```
MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection('mycollection');
```

Now by default, this ends up in a database named "meteor" with a collection named "mycollection"

To insert into that:

```
MyCollection.insert({foo: "bar"});
```

To query that, given that you did not remove the "autopublish" package from your application

```
MyCollection.find();
```

Now this returns a "cursor" not an array so to map that to an array, you do

```
MyCollection.find().fetch();
```

Whereas on mongo shell, you would have done

```
use meteor
db.mycollection.find()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I flagged Michel's as the right answer because it was, I thought. the most helpful for the way my question was worded, but a lot of what you said isn't super clear from the documentation. Infact the documentation is pretty thin when it comes to Meteor and Mongo queries. For example $gte, $lt, and the other operators that DO work in mongo, and then the ones that don't like $date.

Comment: Well yes, they needed to reimplement most of the api so that it could be used in the browser as well. You sometimes get to figure them out yourself. Welcome to the meteor world :)

Answer (score 0):

So on a little bit of thought, I realized I should walk through the issues I had with my stuff, maybe I'm an idiot, but I learned a lot:

1. Publishing was not on for my collection.
2. My syntax was not correct for my database and it was hard to prototype back and forth how to get it working.

Here is what my code looks like for the my helper:

```
myFunction: function () {

    // get from array the date we need and its ISOdate

    selector = Session.get("myCalendarArray");
    today = selector.month[dayPointer];
    today = today["ISOdate"];

    //  set the date for tomorrow, in this case the dates are set at 12:00AM,
    //  so we actually only need half way through the day.

    tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow = tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + .5);


    return MyCollection.find( { releaseDate : { $gte : new Date(today), $lte : new Date(tomorrow) } }  ).fetch()

    }
```

So the issues I finally getting this to work was:

1. the "releaseDate" pointer was in quotes, it apparently needs to be naked, unlike in the shell etc.
2. the `new Date(today)` is the proper way to select dates from the database $date doesn't work.